# message box + vbcancel button + assign a form into it

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
 MsgBox("your order number is" & ordID & ".", vbOK)
        If vbOK Then
            'payments.Show()
            MsgBox("do you want to have another measurement?", vbOKCancel)
            If vbOK Then
                Me.Show()
            ElseIf vbCancel Then
                payments.Show()
            End If
```

i want to assign a form on vbcancel button but, it doesnt perform the condition that i've wanted to. please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of Me.Show? to show the form?
Try the below;

```
    If MsgBox("your order number is" & ordID & ".", vbOK) = vbOk Then

      If MsgBox("do you want to have another measurement?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
         payments.Show()
      End If

    End If
```

Comment: me.show means order form

simply means, if you want to order again, by clicking the vbOK button, it shows the order form again